# How can I prove the hypersurface $M$ is neither convex nor concave?

Tags: several-complex-variables

The question is so simple: how can I prove that $M$ (as defined below) is neither convex nor concave (in the real sense)?

The point here is to define a new notion of convexity, the *complex convexity*, in contrast with the real one; so this example should exhibits a surface $M$ for which, although it isn't convex/concave in the real sense, with this new notion we can say that it's *complex convex*.

The hypersurface is $M:=\partial\Omega$, where $\Omega:=\{(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)\in\Bbb R^4\;:\;y_1<-2x_2^2+y_2^2+\dots\}$ where the dots are terms in $z_2,\bar z_2$ (the book confuses deliberately $\Bbb C^2$ with $\Bbb R^4$ taking one or the other as he wants) of degree $\ge3$.

I try to study the real convexity of $M$ in various ways:

1. With the definition of a convex function in several variables with $f(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)=y_1+2x_2^2-y_2^2-\dots$;
2. Computing the determinant of the Gauss map of the parametrization of the surface (which is the curvature $K$, and we know that the surface is convex iff $K>0$).

But all seems to depend on the (unwritten) terms of degree $\ge3$.

How can I prove that $M$ is neither convex nor concave (in the real sense)?

Comment: No one is able to answer me, there. So I tried here.

Comment: The saddle behavior $+2x_2^2-y_2^2$ seems more than enough for your claim.

Comment: Yes, but the terms of degree $\ge3$ in $z_2,\bar z_2$? I think they have some influence!

Comment: The lower degree terms will dominate the behavior as $x_2,y_2 \to 0$, there's probably some bounding argument.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that point $(0,0,0,0)$ is a point on the boundary.  If we can show that $M$ is not convex nor concave at this point - then we will be done. For ease of notation we write tuples as $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Notice that $\varphi(x) = x_2 +2x^2_3 - x_4^2 - \cdots$ is a defining function. Now calculating the Hessian matrix for $\varphi$ at $(0,0,0,0)$ we get $$\left[\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
 \end{array} \right] $$
To show convexity at $(0,0,0,0)$ fails we need to see that the Hessian matrix isn't positive semidefinite on the tangent space at $(0,0,0,0)$. Similarly to show concavity fails we need that the Hessian matrix isn't negative semidefinite on the tangent space. This is clear since the tangent space consists of $span (e_1,e_3,e_4)$.

For further details see "The Geometry of Domains in Space" page 192.